# How to remove base price+ Custom price from product page in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

Well to start with i am showing default custom option(Purity) price using the link's code

http://sunflowerwww.net/magento-custom-product-option-default-value/ through this i am able to show the default price.

There are to options 14 & 18, now i have made 18's price default on product page. The issue for me is the base price and default custom price add up. I don't want added price rather i just want to show the default custom price.

Please take look http://hottech.in/Royal.png

I googled it but found nothing related to this, i am not able to locate the product listing file.

waiting for some inputs

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) You can use this module: 
>   https://github.com/magebuzz/Magebuzz_Customoption
>
> This module helps you set Default Value For Product Custom Option In
>   Magento. A blog about this module can be found [here](http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/2012/07/09/select-default-value-for-product-custom-option-in-magento).
>
> When you install the above mentioned module, you will see a 
>   `Product Options` menu in your Magento admin. You can set the default custom
>   option for each product from there.
>
> 2) After that, set the price of your product as 0 (zero).
>
> That's all.

Suppose,

- You set your product price as $0.
- You have two custom options with price $55 and $65.
- You set the default chosen options for $55 (From `Product Options` menu in admin).

Then, custom option $55 will be automatically selected when you view the product page and your product price will be displayed as $55. When you select another custom option value, for e.g. $65 then $65 will be displayed as your product price.